# How to set up a repository with Subversion and TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, browser, tortoisesvn, repository

I have Subversion set up on a server in my room and I have TortoiseSVN installed on a client computer and have correctly configured the Subversion service. I don't know how to set up the correct URL to connect to the server because the server doesn't have a URL or anything attached. If i open up the TortoiseSVN repo browser and type in `svn://nameofServer` then the connection works but I don't know how to set up a repository to connect to something like `svn://nameOfServer/TestProject`.

Also I would like to know how to have a password attached to viewing the files and checking them out.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the best option to make the repository available over the network is probably [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html).

**edit**: I'll give an example. If you have created a repository at `d:\svnrepositories\foo`, and you run this:

```
svnserve -d -r d:\svnrepositories
```

then you will be able to reach your repository at `svn://host/foo`, where `host` is the host name or IP address of your server.

Comment: Which is probably what *Subversion service* is.

Comment: when I run the svnserve -d -r c:\svn_repository command the cmd hangs there and nothing happens

Comment: @user596369: perhaps because you are already running svnserve.exe?

Comment: I finally fixed the problem. I had to fix the authentication files so I could then just create folders on the server trough TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 0):

To create a repository you need to run the command [`svnadmin create <name>`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re29.html) on the server.

**Edit:**
The repository you create must be under the repository root. As you access your repository with `svn://...` I assume you are running svnserve to host your repositories.
Have a look at the documentation for [svnserve (section "svnserve as daemon")](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) there you can find out how the repository root is set. If the server is running Linux you can type

```
cat /etc/init.d/svnserve
```

to find out how svnserve is started and where the reposiory root is located.

Comment: Im having trouble getting to the repository i set up. I made a folder on the desktop on the server and then ran that command and set up a repository in it but now dont know how to get the the repository from another computer